# Java autentication of Drupal passwords

Tags: java, drupal, authentication, salt

I try to mimic the way Drupal 7 is checking for a correct password in Java.
Found some code as a guideline here: https://github.com/CraftFire/AuthDB-Legacy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/authdb/scripts/cms/Drupal.java and extracted the code i needed.

The thing is however that when i give the password and the hashed version (in order to extract the salt and amount of iterations needed), i get different results.

The passwords are generated using the Drupal password-hash script
resulting in:

```
Expected   value = $S$DxVn7wubSRzoK9X2pkGx4njeDRkLEgdqPphc2ZXkkb8Viy8JEGf3
Calculated value = $S$DxVn7wubSpQ1CpUnBZZHNqIXMp2XMVZHMYBqAs24NsUHMY7HBkYn

Expected   value = $S$DOASeKfBzZoqgSRl/mBnK06GlLESyMHZ81jyUueEBiCrkkxxArpR
Calculated value = $S$DOASeKfBzs.XMVZ1NkYXNmIqMpEHAoEaMYJ1NmUHCZJaBZFnAZFX
```

Anyone able to help me / tell me what i'm doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

class test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
   // Passwords and hashes generated by Drupal.
   checkPassword("test"  , "$S$DxVn7wubSRzoK9X2pkGx4njeDRkLEgdqPphc2ZXkkb8Viy8JEGf3"); 
   checkPassword("barbaz", "$S$DOASeKfBzZoqgSRl/mBnK06GlLESyMHZ81jyUueEBiCrkkxxArpR");
  }

  private static String itoa64 = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  private static final int DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH = 55;
  private static int password_get_count_log2(String setting) { return itoa64.indexOf(setting.charAt(3)); }

  /**
   * Note: taken from the default Drupal 7 password algorithm
   * @param candidate
   *        the clear text password
   * @param saltedEncryptedPassword
   *        the salted encrypted password string to check => NEEDS TO BE THE DEFAULT DRUPAL 7 PASSWORD HASH.
   * @return true if the candidate matches, false otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean checkPassword(String candidate, String saltedEncryptedPassword) {
    if (candidate == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (saltedEncryptedPassword == null) {
      return false; 
    }

    String hash = password_crypt(candidate, saltedEncryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("Tested value = " + saltedEncryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("Calced value = " + hash);

    return hash == saltedEncryptedPassword;
  }

  public static String SHA512(String text) {
    byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
    try {
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
      md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, text.length());
      sha1hash = md.digest();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertToHex(sha1hash);
  }

  private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
      int two_halfs = 0;
        do {
          if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
            buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
          else
            buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
      }
      while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
  }

  private static String password_crypt(String password, String setting) {
    // The first 12 characters of an existing hash are its setting string.
    setting = setting.substring(0, 12);
    int count_log2 = password_get_count_log2(setting);

    String salt = setting.substring(4, 12);
    // Hashes must have an 8 character salt.
    if (salt.length() != 8) {
      return null; 
    }

    // Convert the base 2 logarithm into an integer.
    int count = 1 << count_log2;

    String hash;
    try {
      hash = SHA512(salt + password);
      do {
        hash = SHA512(hash + password);
      } while (--count >= 0);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return null; 
    }

    int len = hash.length();
    String output = setting + password_base64_encode(hash, len);         
    return (output.length() > 0) ? output.substring(0, DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH) : null;
  }

  private static String password_base64_encode(String input, int count) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0, value;
    do {
      value = input.charAt(i++);
      output.append(itoa64.charAt(value & 0x3f));
      if (i < count) {
        value |= input.charAt(i) << 8;
      }
      output.append(itoa64.charAt((value >> 6) & 0x3f));
      if (i++ >= count) {
        break;
      }
      if (i < count) {
        value |= input.charAt(i) << 16;
      }
      output.append(itoa64.charAt((value >> 12) & 0x3f));
      if (i++ >= count) {
        break;
      }
      output.append(itoa64.charAt((value >> 18) & 0x3f));
    } while (i < count);
    return output.toString();
  }

}
```

--
ps.
One thing i already see is the following:
Consider these functions:

```
  public String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
      int two_halfs = 0;
        do {
          if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
            buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
          else
            buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
      }
      while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
  }
```

and

```
  public String convertToHex(byte [] raw) {
      StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
      for (final byte b : raw) {
         int hiVal = (b & 0xF0) >> 4;
         int loVal = b & 0x0F;
         hex.append((char) ('0' + (hiVal + (hiVal / 10 * 7))));
         hex.append((char) ('0' + (loVal + (loVal / 10 * 7))));
      }
      return hex.toString();
   }
```

The first function returns the string as a lowercase, the second is returned as higher case string. Don't know which to use, both are returning different results in the end, but neither is satisfying.

-Edit-

Almost there???...

Came a step further, changes the question a bit...
In Drupal the following function is used:

```
$hash = hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE);
```

that returns

```
'���Y�emb
ӈ3����4��q����h�osab��V�!IS�uC�*[�
```

As you see, we do not need the hex version, since you get a total different hash back...
So i altered the code in java:

```
  public byte[] SHA512(String text) {
    byte[] sha1hash = new byte[50];
    try {
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
      md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, text.length());
      sha1hash = md.digest();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sha1hash;
  }

 --snip--
  hash = new String(SHA512(salt + password));
  System.out.println(hash);
```

that returns:

```
'���Y�emb
ӈ3����4��q���h�osab��V�!IS�uC�*[�
```

As you see thats ALMOST the same....

```
php:  ӈ3����4��q����h�osab��V�!IS�uC�*[�
java: ӈ3����4��q���h�osab��V�!IS�uC�*[�
```

Anyone got a clue how to fix that last part?
The form new String(SHA512(salt + password,'Whatevercodec')); did not help me...
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you do something like this:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class hash {

private static final int DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH = 55;

private static String _password_itoa64() {
    return "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Passwords and hashes generated by Drupal.
    checkPassword("adrian", "$S$DNbBTrkalsPChLsqajHUQS18pBBxzSTQW0310SzivTy7HDQ.zgyG");
    checkPassword("test"  , "$S$DxVn7wubSRzoK9X2pkGx4njeDRkLEgdqPphc2ZXkkb8Viy8JEGf3");
    checkPassword("barbaz", "$S$DOASeKfBzZoqgSRl/mBnK06GlLESyMHZ81jyUueEBiCrkkxxArpR");
}


private static int password_get_count_log2(String setting) {
    return _password_itoa64().indexOf(setting.charAt(3));
}


private static byte[] sha512(String input) {
    try {
        return java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest(input.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new byte[0];
}

private static byte[] sha512(byte[] input) {
    try {
        return java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest(input);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new byte[0];
}

/**
 * Note: taken from the default Drupal 7 password algorithm
 *
 * @param candidate               the clear text password
 * @param saltedEncryptedPassword the salted encrypted password string to check => NEEDS TO BE THE DEFAULT DRUPAL 7 PASSWORD HASH.
 * @return true if the candidate matches, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean checkPassword(String candidate, String saltedEncryptedPassword) throws Exception {
    if (candidate == null || saltedEncryptedPassword == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String hash = password_crypt(candidate, saltedEncryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("Expected value = " + saltedEncryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("Calced   value = " + hash);
    System.out.println("Result Good?   = " + saltedEncryptedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(hash));


    return saltedEncryptedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(hash);
}


private static String password_crypt(String password, String passwordHash) throws Exception {
    // The first 12 characters of an existing hash are its setting string.
    passwordHash = passwordHash.substring(0, 12);
    int count_log2 = password_get_count_log2(passwordHash);
    String salt = passwordHash.substring(4, 12);
    // Hashes must have an 8 character salt.
    if (salt.length() != 8) {
        return null;
    }

    int count = 1 << count_log2;


    byte[] hash;
    try {
        hash = sha512(salt.concat(password));

        do {
            hash = sha512(joinBytes(hash, password.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } while (--count > 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    String output = passwordHash + _password_base64_encode(hash, hash.length);
    return (output.length() > 0) ? output.substring(0, DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH) : null;
}

private static byte[] joinBytes(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte[] combined = new byte[a.length + b.length];

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, combined, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, combined, a.length, b.length);
    return combined;
}



private static String _password_base64_encode(byte[] input, int count) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0;
    CharSequence itoa64 = _password_itoa64();
    do {
        long value = SignedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i++]);

        output.append(itoa64.charAt((int) value & 0x3f));
        if (i < count) {
            value |= SignedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i]) << 8;
        }
        output.append(itoa64.charAt((int) (value >> 6) & 0x3f));
        if (i++ >= count) {
            break;
        }
        if (i < count) {
            value |=  SignedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i]) << 16;
        }

        output.append(itoa64.charAt((int) (value >> 12) & 0x3f));
        if (i++ >= count) {
            break;
        }
        output.append(itoa64.charAt((int) (value >> 18) & 0x3f));
    } while (i < count);

    return output.toString();
}


public static long SignedByteToUnsignedLong(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}

}
```

Comment: You saved me sooo much time !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Adrian for the excellent code.  You saved me a lot of time!  I just wanted to post a follow up that does not squash exceptions, removes main() and console output and properly named Java functions.  A unit test follows too.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class PhpassHashedPassword {

    private static final int DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH = 55;

    private static final String ITOA_64 = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    private static int passwordGetCount(String setting) {
        return ITOA_64.indexOf(setting.charAt(3));
    }

    private static byte[] sha512(byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest(input);
    }

    /**
     * Note: taken from the default Drupal 7 password algorithm
     *
     * @param candidate the clear text password
     * @param saltedEncryptedPassword the salted encrypted password string to
     * check => NEEDS TO BE THE DEFAULT DRUPAL 7 PASSWORD HASH.
     * @return true if the candidate matches, false otherwise.
     * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static boolean validatePasswordHash(String candidate, String saltedEncryptedPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (candidate == null || saltedEncryptedPassword == null) {
            return false;
        }

        String hash = password_crypt(candidate, saltedEncryptedPassword);
        return saltedEncryptedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(hash);
    }

    private static String password_crypt(String password, String passwordHash) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // The first 12 characters of an existing hash are its setting string.
        passwordHash = passwordHash.substring(0, 12);
        int count_log2 = passwordGetCount(passwordHash);
        String salt = passwordHash.substring(4, 12);
        // Hashes must have an 8 character salt.
        if (salt.length() != 8) {
            return null;
        }

        int count = 1 << count_log2;

        byte[] hash = sha512(salt.concat(password).getBytes());

        do {
            hash = sha512(joinBytes(hash, password.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } while (--count > 0);

        String output = passwordHash + passwordBase64Encode(hash, hash.length);
        return (output.length() > 0) ? output.substring(0, DRUPAL_HASH_LENGTH) : null;
    }

    private static byte[] joinBytes(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        byte[] combined = new byte[a.length + b.length];

        System.arraycopy(a, 0, combined, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, combined, a.length, b.length);
        return combined;
    }

    private static String passwordBase64Encode(byte[] input, int count) {

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        do {
            long value = signedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i++]);

            output.append(ITOA_64.charAt((int) value & 0x3f));
            if (i < count) {
                value |= signedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i]) << 8;
            }
            output.append(ITOA_64.charAt((int) (value >> 6) & 0x3f));
            if (i++ >= count) {
                break;
            }
            if (i < count) {
                value |= signedByteToUnsignedLong(input[i]) << 16;
            }

            output.append(ITOA_64.charAt((int) (value >> 12) & 0x3f));
            if (i++ >= count) {
                break;
            }
            output.append(ITOA_64.charAt((int) (value >> 18) & 0x3f));
        } while (i < count);

        return output.toString();
    }

    private static long signedByteToUnsignedLong(byte b) {
        return b & 0xFF;
    }

}
```

Here is a unit test:

```
public class PhpassHashedPasswordTest {

    public PhpassHashedPasswordTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testGoodPassword() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if(!PhpassHashedPassword.validatePasswordHash("Y0dog!", "$S$EU44gErBh91wY1I8eEfEyymUNfFqh8OXLYeAdm.1xVnjgkN9KauF")) {
            fail("expected password to match");
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMismatchPassword() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if(PhpassHashedPassword.validatePasswordHash("THEWRONGPASSWORD", "$S$EU44gErBh91wY1I8eEfEyymUNfFqh8OXLYeAdm.1xVnjgkN9KauF")) {
            fail("expected password match to fail");
        }
    }


}
```